# Could not load type 'abc.MvcApplication'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, parse-platform

I am getting this error- and have no idea so far,

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
Source Error:
Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="abc.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Comment: Check the namespace and class name in Global.asax.cs, make sure it matches with markup present in Global.asax file.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes ,both are same...